# Validity of a result from character theory for finite field.

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Corollary $11.29$ of the book *Character Theory of Finite Groups* by I. Martin Isaacs as given:

> Corollary $11.29:$ Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and $\zeta\in Irr(G), \xi\in Irr(H)$, be a constituent of $\zeta_{H}$. Then $\zeta(1)/ \xi(1)$ divides $|G:H|.$

My question is can i say that above corollary is valid over any field or only for $C?$ Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: sorry i will edit...

Comment: @MatthewTowers i edit it.....

Comment: What is your proof for $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: It is given in book ...